# Filter Subform with ComboBox on Main Form Not Working

Tags: vba, combobox

Trying to filter a Subform with a ComboBox I have on my Main Form...

**Main Form - Record Source** - Inventory Material Query

**Query -** Inventory Material Query

**SQL -** SELECT [RM Products].Product, [Inventory Material].[Lot No], [Inventory Material].[Date Rcvd], [Inventory Material].Height, [Inventory Material].Length, [Inventory Material].Width, [Inventory Material].[WO #], [Inventory Material].QTY, [Inventory Material].[Cut Height], [Inventory Material].[Cut Length], [Inventory Material].[Cut Width], [Height]*[Width]*[Length]*0.2833 AS Weight, [Height]-[Cut Height] AS [New Height], [Length]-[Cut Length] AS [New Length], [Width]-[Cut Width] AS [New Width], [Cut Height]*[Cut Length]*[Cut Width]*0.2833 AS [Cut Weight]
FROM [RM Products] INNER JOIN [Inventory Material] ON [RM Products].Product = [Inventory Material].Product;

**Combo42** (On Main Form = Inventory Material - Cut Orders) Unbound

**RowSource** = qryProd

**SQL** = SELECT [RM Products].ID, [RM Products].Product FROM [RM Products]; UNION SELECT "*", "" FROM [RM Products];

**Sub-Form - Source Object** = Inventory Material Query subform

Link Master Field = Product

Link Child Field = Product

*Issue #1 = Unable to see all records from Inventory Material Query in my Sub-form upon open Main Form; Sub-form only shows certain records*

*Issue #2 = Unable to get VBA Code to filter Sub-form based on selection in ComboBox (Combo42)*

I've looked through countless websites, threads and other postings to figure out what I am doing wrong and I need HELP!!